# Two variables not equaling each-other for if statement

Tags: macos, bash, variables, if-statement

Hello I am having a problem with checking two variables to see whether or not they are both equal. I have the following script:

```
Output=$(sudo defaults read /System/Library/User\ Template/English.lproj/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SetupAssistant | grep -o "DidSeeCloudSetup = 1")
Output2=$(sudo defaults read /System/Library/User\ Template/English.lproj/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SetupAssistant | grep -o "LastSeenCloudProductVersion")
Check="DidSeeCloudSetup = 1"
Check2="LastSeenCloudProductVersion"

echo "$Output"
echo "$Check"
if [ "$Output" = "$Check" ]
    then
       echo "OK"
      else
    echo "FALSE"
```

Even though they both contain the same thing it always comes out false... any ideas why?

Comment: What do your `echo` statements show? I'd also include some other start and end character in the echo (e.g. echo "-${output}-"case there is a non-viewable character in there (space, etc.).

Comment: Add `| hexdump -C` or `| xxd` or `| od` to the end of both of those `echo` commands and see if they are actually the same.

Comment: Darn, Etan, I was halfway through typing a recommendation to use `od -c` when your comment came in.  :)

Comment: @EtanReisner I tacked on | od and they came out exactly the same which is why I am stumped on why the if statement is not coming out "OK"

Comment: The variables obtained via `$(...)` most likely still have the newlines attached to them, while your `Check` variables do not...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a special character (hex: 10) between `$` and `Check` in your if clause:

```
00000000  69 66 20 5b 20 22 24 4f  75 74 70 75 74 22 20 3d  |if [ "$Output" =|
00000010  20 22 24 10 43 68 65 63  6b 22 20 5d 0a           | "$.Check" ].|
```

Comment: What do you mean Cyrus?

Comment: He's right. There is something odd on that line (though I can't get it to show up here reliably). Run your script through `od` and you should see it.

Comment: Remove `"$Check"` in your if clause and type `"` `$` `C` `h` `e` `c` `k` `"` again. Don't copy `"$Check"` and don't insert it again with your mouse/clipboard.

Comment: Wow how weird, thank you guys so much! How do you go about running it through od so I can check future scripts for similar problems?

Comment: You can check your file with `cat -v file`. Then you can see this in your code: `if [ "$Output" = "$^PCheck" ]`. This is an option of GNU cat.